# I would like to slice the first part of a string before the '|'

Tags: python, slice

i would like to slice different strings at a certain point . To be specific, i want to print the part of the sring before the first '|' .

```
data=' xbox 360 | 10000 | NEW '
length=len(data)

for i in range(length):
    if (data[i]=='|'):
        product=data[:i]

print(product)
```

However when i run the code the result is this:

**xbox 360 | 10000**

i want it to show only:

**xbox 360**

Comment: `data.split('|')[0].strip()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is `.split()` as below:

```
the_stuff = data.split('|')[0]
```

This will split the line using `|` as the delimiter and give the results in a tuple, but the `[0]` only returns the first offset in the tuple which is everything before the first `|`.

If you want all 3 components, then you just need:

```
tuple_of_the_stuff = data.split('|')
```

And now you have a tuple of:  `(' xbox 360 ', ' 10000 ', ' NEW ')`

Edit:  and as suggested below, you can use `.strip()` to clean up the resulting values of your tuple at some point.

Comment: You should include `strip()` as well to remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Agreed.  I just figured at some point, they have to do some of the work themselves.  ;)

Comment: Or `.split(' | ')`

Comment: your comments helped a lot and the solution you gave me worked, but i still don't understand why the code doesn't stop at the first '|' . Just to know

Comment: In python, `.split()` will separate a string at EVERY occurrence of the delimiter.  You can alter the default behavior with a second argument.  For example, `var.split('|', 1)` will split the string `var` at the first `|` character, giving you a tuple of 2 strings.